# I want to change the menu bar to sidebar in flask-admin

Tags: sidebar, flask-admin

admin i have 45 models in my project i want to add them all in admin panel, i'm using flask-admin for admin panel, here i want to change the menu bar because if add more than 15 views remaining views are not visible so i would like to integrate the side bar, I tried from morning but i can't found a solution, someone please help me.

My menu bar looks like [image]

I want a side bar like a drop down to show all the models views from there i want to redirect to list view.

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple we can add a category then we can select the specific table and we can move to that table

```
    self.add_view(SchoolView(School, app.db_session, category='Models'))
```